# Universal App ListView Item HorizontalAlignment

Tags: xaml, listview, win-universal-app, windows-10

I would like to create a ListView that has right aligned items as well as left aligned.  So far in all my attempts with DataTemplates and ItemContainerStyles, I am not able to get this working.  The left alignment works fine as that is the default, but I cannot figure out how to get some items right-aligned.  For example, this would be similar to a chat/conversation type view like the Windows Phone Messaging app.

My current XAML looks like this:

```
<Page
x:Class="MDControl.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:MDControl"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Page.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Name="Messages" Source="{Binding mMessages}"/>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="SentMessageTemplate">
        <StackPanel Padding="10" Margin="5" Background="Teal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="Auto">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding MessageType}" FontWeight="Bold" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Foreground="White"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding MessageBody}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="White" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Timestamp}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Foreground="White" FontStyle="Italic" FontSize="12"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="ReceivedMessageTemplate">
        <StackPanel Padding="10" Margin="5" Background="LightGray">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding MessageType}" FontWeight="Bold" TextWrapping="NoWrap"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding MessageBody}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Timestamp}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" TextAlignment="Right" FontStyle="Italic" FontSize="12"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem" x:Key="SentMessageStyle">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem" x:Key="ReceivedMessageStyle">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    </Style>

    <local:MessageListTemplateSelector x:Key="MessageListTemplateSelector"
        SentMessageTemplate="{StaticResource SentMessageTemplate}"
        ReceivedMessageTemplate="{StaticResource ReceivedMessageTemplate}">
    </local:MessageListTemplateSelector>

    <local:MessageListContainerStyleSelector x:Key="MessageListContainerStyleSelector"
        SentMessageStyle="{StaticResource SentMessageStyle}"
        ReceivedMessageStyle="{StaticResource ReceivedMessageStyle}">
    </local:MessageListContainerStyleSelector>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ListView x:Name="messageList" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ItemContainerStyleSelector="{StaticResource MessageListContainerStyleSelector}" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Messages}}" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MessageListTemplateSelector}" Margin="10,120,10,50" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" IsDoubleTapEnabled="False"/>
</Grid>
```

What can I change to get the "Sent" messages to be right aligned? Currently they show up with a Teal background which I want, but they are still Left aligned instead of Right. I am a little new to XAML, so forgive me if I'm way off here.

**UPDATE: Solution**

Grids were the key, I ended up having to use multiple grids to achieve the correct right-alignment, in conjunction with an `ItemContainerStyle` setting the `HorizontalContentAlignment`.

```
<Page
x:Class="MDControl.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:MDControl"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Page.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Name="Messages" Source="{Binding mMessages}"/>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="SentMessageTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid Height="Auto" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <StackPanel Padding="10" Background="Teal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding MessageType}" FontWeight="Bold" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Foreground="White" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding MessageBody}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="White" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Timestamp}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Foreground="White" FontStyle="Italic" FontSize="12" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="ReceivedMessageTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid Height="Auto" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <StackPanel Padding="10" Background="LightGray">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding MessageType}" FontWeight="Bold" TextWrapping="NoWrap" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding MessageBody}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Timestamp}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" FontStyle="Italic" FontSize="12" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

    <local:MessageListTemplateSelector x:Key="MessageListTemplateSelector"
        SentMessageTemplate="{StaticResource SentMessageTemplate}"
        ReceivedMessageTemplate="{StaticResource ReceivedMessageTemplate}">
    </local:MessageListTemplateSelector>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <ListView x:Name="messageList" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Messages}}" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MessageListTemplateSelector}" Margin="10,120,10,50" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" IsDoubleTapEnabled="False">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your DataTemplates , not in styles or etc.You must use Grid instead of Stackpanel in your DataTemplate to achieve that.

Stackpanels won't stretch to parent.They'll only get the width / height of all controls inside it.Try something like

```
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Comment: Thanks!  This didn't get me all the way there but let me down the right path. Edited the original post with the full solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should use HorizontalAlignment  property which defines the position of the element inside a parent element.`<Grid x:Name="simpleGrid" height = 50 width = 100 HorizontalAlignment="right" />`

Comment: I'm using `HorizontalAlignment="Right"` in the `SentMessageTemplate` in the sample code I provided. I've also tried that in the `SentMessageStyle` as well. Neither works. Can you be more specific as to where you think I should be setting that?